Unable to empty clipboard in AutoHotKey v2.0.18
So, I was trying to update a script using the Clipboard of Windows 11. The script was nothing much; just a hotstring. It inserts a string of characters, with the SendText command. However, I decided Clipboard was better as it was more reliable, and was much faster. The main reason is a certain "keydelay" issue. Sometimes, AHK would kinda "lag" and wait for my input before inserting any more characters from the given string. So, I decided Clipboard would be kind of like a Get Out of Jail for Free card, avoiding the annoying issue completely. However, Clipboard turned out to be more of a roadblock than ever; But this time, it is probably an actual bug, either with the system or with AutoHotKey.
The code snippet I used for testing:-
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance

!,::Clipboard := ""

What it's supposed to do is clear the entire clipboard, when I press Alt + ,. The hotkey part doesn't matter much; only the action it's supposed to execute does.
I would expect Clipboard := "" to empty the clipboard. I had used it for a test. I was trying to see if it actually empties the Windows clipboard. But, believe it or not, it never did. I had also tried Clipboard=  and A_Clipboard := "" but in vain.
So, what could be the issue here? Thanks.

Edit:- The issue seems to be with my system, it doesn't support it. Is there any alternative to it?


Update:- I understood the function wrong. Clipboard := "" prevents Ctrl+V from sending the latest entry. The real question is How do you clear parts of the clipboard history?


Update 2:- See my answer given below, I found the solution to what I need by myself. PS the Clipboard and A_Clipboard variables reference the Clipboard. What I really needed was a way to delete an entry from the clipboard history. Needed to get the wording right


The built-in variable "Clipboard" of AHK v1 is replaced in AHK v2 by A_Clipboard.
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance

!,:: A_Clipboard := ""

The 'A_' prefix indicates that the variable is a built-in Variable.
Try it first in a script with no other code and close all other scripts for the case that something else interferes.
EDIT:
To delete the first entry from the legacy clipboard, use this:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance

!,:: Run "cmd.exe" " /c`"echo off | clip"

To delete all the data in the legacy clipboard, create a batch file, add this code to it
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo off | clip"
wmic service where "name like '%%cbdhsvc_%%'" call stopservice
wmic service where "name like '%%cbdhsvc_%%'" call startservice

and run it manuell or use the run command to run it from your script.
For details see https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clear-clipboard-data-shortcut-windows-10

Nope… As mentioned in the question, A_Clipboard doesn't work either…Exact same code, but still no effect.

Works fine here (Windows11 Build 22631.3958 (23H2) , AutoHotkey v2.0.18).

Oh… I'm using Windows 11 Pro 21H2, if that matters. Is there a bug in this Windows version? Can you provide an alternative?

You can download the current official release here .

Try also other key combinations or the On Screen Keyboard. If it works, your keyboard needs some cleaning,

Nope, does seem to be an issue with the windows update... It's not an issue with the keyboard, so I'll have to update the OS itself...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

See also EDIT in this answer.

So, the chat is now gone, for some reason…
Anyways, we were just discussing about the different ways to fiddle with the clipboard history. None of them worked for me. The one given in my answer, however, does.

So, I just found out about this library discussed here, and it was a one fits all solution for AHKv2. The only issue was that the example code and the library were not provided seperately. Just for reference for people who visit this later, the library part begins from the class ClipboardHistory line in the code.
BTW go to this forum page for the v1 version, although for this one you will need to use it like a normal object and define it in a variable, using new ClipboardHistory as the value. (I do not know the correct wording…)
